# Check if ASPX checkbox is checked with javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

How can I check if the checkbox is checked or not on page load with Javascript? None of the codes worked:

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkEmailConsent" Checked='<%# bool.Parse(Eval("EmailConsent").ToString()) %>' Enabled="false" />


document.getElementById("<%= chkEmailConsent.ClientID %>")

document.getElementById("ctl00_cphGlobalContent_FormView1_chkEmailConsentID")
```

Answer (score 0):

I like using the same name for my controls both server and client side so I add ClientIDMode="Static".  That way I do not have to use the <%= stuff to get the control name.

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ClientIdMode="Static" ID="chkEmailConsent" Checked='<%# bool.Parse(Eval("EmailConsent").ToString()) %>' Enabled="false" />


<script> 
        // note, this works only because I check the value after the control.
        // otherwise it would need to be in a function or something like that

        alert(document.getElementById("chkEmailConsent").checked)

</script>
```

Comment: Im still getting this error in the console: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of null

Comment: Look at your raw html.  The name you are using is probably wrong.  Did you try setting the ClientIDMode like I suggested? Post the raw html for us to look at.

Comment: you did put your document.getElementById("<%= chkEmailConsent.ClientID %>") inside script tags yes?

Comment: yes I tried both ways. If I use <%= chkEmailConsent.ClientID %> Im getting ASP error: Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'chkEmailConsent' does not exist in the current context. If I use document.getElementById("chkEmailConsent" > I have javascript error as mentioned above.

Comment: still would like to see your raw html. Something else may be going on.

Comment: I have added markup to my edited question. What do u mean by "raw html" ?

Comment: When the page has loaded, right click then click view source. That way, you can check and see what the control's actual HTML markup looks liked.

Comment: worked with: <script type="text/javascript">                          alert(document.getElementById("ctl00_cphGlobalContent_FormView1_chkEmailConsent").checked);
                        </script>